# mod-rewrite redirect parent URL to sibling URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've read over the similar questions on stackoverflow, but have been unable to get this working. I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop.

I'm trying to redirect a specific url to a child of that url. eg:

`Redirect 301 /category/parent-cat http://domain.com/category/parent_cat/child_cat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with mod_alias, you could use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead so that you could anchor the pattern at the end of the URL:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/$1/child_cat
```

The mod_rewrite solution is almost identical:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/$1/child_cat [R=301,L]
```

You could naturally replace the `[^/]+` patterns with the specific paths you were looking for, as well. I thought I'd provide a more general solution just in case, though.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I had troubles with the Rewrite, but the Redirect works great. Thanks for providing a general solution as well!